# Low correlation value but high quotient

Tags: correlation

In R I have a dataset `promotion` and another dataset `new_users` for each hours in a day. `dim(promotion)=193 24` and `dim(new_users)=193 24`

So `head(promotion)` gives

```
      V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21
1  1  2  2  0  0  1  1  5  3   3   3   4   4   4   3   3   2   1   2   6   5
2  2  0  0  0  1  1  2  3  3   1   2   2   5   3   3   1   3   1   2   3   6
3  2  1  2  2  4  2  3  6  6   4   9   7   7   9   8   6   5   5   6   4   7
4  6  3  2  0  2  1  0  1  2   1   1   2   1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  4   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   3
6  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2   2   1   2   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0
  V22 V23 V24
1   5   6   2
2   1   2   7
3   4  11   7
4   1   0   1
5   1   1   1
6   0   0   0
```

whereas `head(new_users)` gives

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21
1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  2   1   1   3   9   5  12  11   7  11   5  14  14
2  7  1  3  2  0  1  1  3  2   6   9   6   5   8  12   7  14  16  11  14  19
3  7  1  1  1  1  1  3  3  4   6   7   8  22  10  19  18  16  16  13  20  10
4  1  2  2  0  0  1  0  4  7   2   6   6   7   9   3   4   6   5  13   3   6
5  1  0  0  1  1  0  1  2  4   6   4   3   2   7   1   4   5  11   3  13  10
6  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  4  2   6   4   7   3   2   4   5   4   8  14   7   9
  V22 V23 V24
1  10   0   2
2  11  11   7
3   8  11   6
4   2   0   2
5   3   2   3
6   5   2   1
```

Now for each hours I want to calculate the correlation between `promotion` and `new_users`. In R I do this

```
corr=c()
for(j in 1:24)  {
h=cbind(promotion[,j],new_users[,j])
corr[j] = cor.test(h[,1],h[,2], alternative="greater",method="pearson" )$estimate
 }
```

where the hypothesis is, that there is not positive correlation against the alternative hypothesis  that there is a positive correlation.

I get these correlations-value for each hour

```
[1] -0.004365943  0.057143049  0.019965735 -0.009082763  0.024618575
 [6] -0.076012180  0.015401301 -0.053603118  0.170855851 -0.005217288
[11]  0.005104891  0.253814298  0.252274772  0.154165103  0.341692734
[16]  0.141843370  0.070887960  0.051190216  0.106422766  0.078130045
[21]  0.167922398  0.105443213  0.095502165  0.188213970
```

Now I want to calculate the quotient , ie new_users for each promotion.

```
col=c()
for(j in 1:24)  {
col[j] <- sum(new_users[,j])/sum(promotion[,j])
}
```

This gives me this output

```
 [1] 0.8021978 1.7894737 1.7714286 3.8125000 1.0845070 1.2842105 1.1685393
 [8] 1.1000000 0.9393258 1.0870536 1.1233184 1.6129032 1.6222760 1.3982684
[15] 1.7456359 2.9314516 1.9717514 2.6331361 2.5803815 2.0771144 1.9431525
[22] 1.4424084 0.7556008 0.5657568
```

and this is very strange, because entry 4 has the highest value at 3.81 but the correlation-value is very low, namely -0.009. Intuitively if an entry has a high quotient then it should also have a high correlation-value.

What am I missing ?

My main goal is to find which hours has strongest correlation; so which hours I should chose to improve the promotion to get more new_users.

Comment: Is it correct that the correlation test inside the for-loop is independent of the loop-variable $j$? Are you intending to calculate the same thing 24 times?

Comment: And how do you get a 1 bij 24 matrix/vector when dividing new_users by promotions? Isn't it element-wise division which wouldn't change the dimensions?

Comment: I have made the change.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're trying to find do, but a high quotient between the sum of x and the sum of y does not say anything about the correlation:

```
x1 <- seq(1:10)
y1 <- seq(1:10)
cor(x1,y1)

[1] 1

sum(x1)/sum(y1)

[1] 1
```

Correlation is 1 and the quotient is 1.

```
y2 <- y1 + 10
cor(x1,y2)

[1] 1

sum(x1)/sum(y2)

[1] 0.3548387
```

Correlation is still 1, but quotient is 0.35.

```
y3 <- y1 - 10
cor(x1,y3)

[1] 1

sum(x1)/sum(y3)

[1] -1.222222
```

Correlation is again 1, but now the quotient is negative.

```
set.seed(1)
x2 <- sample(1000:2000, 10)
cor(x2,y1)

[1] 0.0666171

sum(x2)/sum(y1)

[1] 281.6364
```

Correlation is nearly 0, but the quotient is very high.

As you can see, you shouldn't at all expect a linear relationship between correlation and your quotient of the sums. This can of course be explained mathematically as well, but I think these examples are sufficient.

Comment: Ok, I understand that now. If one would ask: which hours has strongest correlation, ie improve promotion will improve new_users. How should one approach this ?

Comment: I'm note sure I understand what promotion and new users mean. Can you tell us a bit more about the design of the study?

Comment: Promotion is an commercial in television. When people see it some of them will be new_user (signing up). So I want to investigate which hours a day these commercial have the highest effect on people, so they can signed up.

Comment: Ok, I get it! I'll edit my answer to provide a possible solution next week unless somebody beats me to it. Just one question: what does the rows represent? Are they different days or different commercials?

Comment: The rows are simply the times a commercial had been used. One commercial is 20 second commercial on television. So if promotion is 3 it simply means that in that hour we had a commercial 3 times.

Comment: Have you done any thoughts? I created a forum here where we all can discuss the issue: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47745/realationships-between-correlation-and-quotient

Comment: Time to think, yes. Time to write, no. I'll get back to you.

Comment: I think you should do a Poisson regression model. I don't have the time to formulate a good answer right now. Perhaps you could post a new question about how to analyze your data in order to answer your research question.